# How can I tell Visual Studio I have code not in App_Code folder?

Tags: visual-studio

We've been using Visual Studio 2005 Team Suite for a fairly large web project.  Now, we're adding another web app into our current project...it is essentially complete, and we're just adding the entire thing as a folder into our current project.  The project builds, runs...everything is fine...but this new sub-project doesn't have any kind of Intellisense that recognizes the classes we've created for this sub-project.

I think that this is probably because the code for the project isn't in the App_Code folder, and so Visual Studio doesn't know where to find it.  Does that make sense?  If so, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As fas as I know, that's just the way it is. For some reason, the default template for web apps in 2005 does it like this. If you just need small stuff, making the classes not in App_Code implement an interface, and then just use this when you interact with your code that reside somewhere outside of App_Code (for whatever reasons).

Otherwise, you can choose to use a different project model (doesn't ship with 2005, so need to be installed seperatly, and conversion could be non-trivial):
http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/Migration2/Migration2.aspx

Comment: *sigh*  Okay...not the answer I was hoping for, but I guess that's as good as it gets.  Thanks!